# Angular Relative Form Based On Drop down value need to change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a Reactive form in angular 7 that containing 2 dropdowns (select) working as cascading dropdown, the problem the cascading dropdown not works, when I choose the first select box [object Object] in value change for your referral  [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igz5uu)

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="reportForm">
   <div class='col-12 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group " >
         <label >Transformation Type</label>
         <select name="select" formControlName="transformationType" class="form-control"  placeholder="Select User Type" >
            <option value="0" disabled selected>Select a Criteria</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of datasources" [value]="item">{{item.title}}</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class='col-12 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group " >
         <label >User Type:</label>
         <select formControlName="whereInput" class="form-control">
            <option value="0"  selected>Select an Option</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of units" [value]="item">{{item}}</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Component:

```
this.ifscSingle.controls.transformationType.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use a complex `value` type for each `<option>` element such as `object`, use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`:

```
<form [formGroup]="reportForm">
   <div class='col-12 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group " >
         <label >Transformation Type</label>
         <select name="select" formControlName="transformationType" class="form-control"  placeholder="Select User Type" >
            <option value="0" disabled selected>Select a Criteria</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of datasources" [ngValue]="item">{{item.title}}</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class='col-12 col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group " >
         <label >User Type:</label>
         <select formControlName="whereInput" class="form-control">
            <option value="0"  selected>Select an Option</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of units" [ngValue]="item">{{item}}</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tktsjv) in action.

As a side note, I'd recommend to set the default `<option>` value to an empty string `""` to match your reactive form control(s) default values as currently your code fails to display the `"Select a Criteria"` and `"Select an Option"` on load. Also you can remove the `selected` attribute(s) as that is effectively done by Angular depending current reactive form value:

```
<option value="">Select a Criteria</option>

<!-- your other stuff -->

<option value="">Select an Option</option>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to patch value after the reactive form has been created to reflect the change.

For example :

```
this.reportForm.patchValue({
  formControlName1: myValue1, 
  // formControlName2: myValue2 (can be omitted)
});
```

In your scenario, you need to patch `reportForm` once the value is changed for transformation type.

```
 this.reportForm.get('transformationType').valueChanges.subscribe(item => {

      this.units = item.units
      this.reportForm.patchValue({
      whereInput: this.units, 
});

    })
```

And in HTML code instead of `value` use `ngValue`.

```
<select name="select" formControlName="transformationType" class="form-control"  placeholder="Select User Type" >
            <option value="0" disabled selected>Select a Criteria</option>
            <option *ngFor="let item of datasources" [ngValue]="item">{{item.title}}</option>
         </select>
```

Here is the working solution of your problem:

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-smdbuk)